# How to merge array elements with comma separated value without using explode function

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, multidimensional-array

I want to merge array elements into comma separated values.
This is an array

```
array:12 [
    0 => array:2 [
        "name" => "A1"
        "project" => array:1 [
            0 => "New Project"
        ]
    ]
    1 => array:2 [
        "name" => "A2"
        "project" => array:2 [
            0 => "New Project"
            2 => "Project"
        ]
    ]
]
```

My expected array should be like this

```
array:12 [
    0 => array:2 [
        "name" => "A1"
        "project" => array:1 [
            0 => "New Project"
        ]
    ]
    1 => array:2 [
        "name" => "A2"
        "project" => array:2 [
            0 => "New Project","Project"
        ]
    ]
]
```

Need to merge New Project and Project in one position from array 2

Comment: with this associative array, I think the closest you would be able to get would be encapsulating both projects as a comma separating string like "New project, project" - does that sound okay?

Comment: _"I want to merge New Project and Project in one position from array 2"_ - That's not what your example shows. `0 => "New Project","Project"` is actually two array items and equivalent to `0 => "New Project", 1 => "Project"`. You probably mean `0 => "New Project, Project"` (inside the same quotes, making it one value). If that is what you mean, you should edit your question to reflect that.

Comment: Why not use implode()?  It does pretty much what you want though you'll have to loop the array and apply it to the sub-array, but that's also true of most other solutions too)

Comment: You have shown the output you want, but not the code you are using to get there. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can help you correct your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this snippet of [array_walk](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php),

```
array_walk($arr, function(&$val){
    $val['project'] = implode(",", $val['project']);
});
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/LXn3L).

Answer (score 0):

use [implode](https://php.net/implode)

```
$arr = array:12 [
     0 => array:2 [
        "name" => "A1"
      "project" => array:1 [
            0 => "New Project"
          ]
        ]  
       1 => array:2 [
         "name" => "A2"
          "project" => array:2 [
               0 => "New Project"
               2 => "Project"
           ]
      ]


foreach ($arr as &$value) {
   implode(', ', $value['project']);
 }
```